# How to send data from main form to second form?

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms, for example FormA and FormB. In FormA I have 1 textBox, 2 numericupdowns and a button. In FormB i have listBox. I want to type something in textBox, select numbers and press the button on FormA, open FormB and in listBox to be the word i typed in FormA(textbox) and numbers I selected in numericUpDowns.

Comment: To those downvoting, let the OP know what to improve.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far, otherwise the question is too broad to be able to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the new form like this:

```cs
FormB form = new FormB(...);
```

you can access its properties and methods:

```cs
form.methodX();
```

With this knowledge, you can store an instance of FormB in a private variable in FormA and create a public method on FormB that will allow you to manipulate the contents of FormB.

```cs
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    private FormB formb;

    private void OpenFormB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.formb = new FormB();
        formb.Show();
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.formb?.UpdateList(...);
    }
}
```